# How to retrive blob value from database using hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I am developing one desktop application which i used Hibernate to connect mySql database, In that database the table doesn't have the primary key. so am getting the pojo class has two java file. The pojo class is,

```
package pojo;
public class Entries implements java.io.Serializable {

    private EntriesId id;

    public Entries() {
    }

    public Entries(EntriesId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public EntriesId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(EntriesId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

//POJO2

```
package pojo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

public class EntriesId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String userid;
    private String name;
    private Integer ver;
    private String bexval;
    private String boidval;
    private Integer empid;
    private String fieldname;
    private byte[] fieldvalue;
    private Date lstdatetime;

    public EntriesId() {
    }

    public EntriesId(String userid, String name, Integer ver, String bexval,
            String boidval, Integer empid, String fieldname, byte[] fieldvalue,
            Date lstdatetime) {
        this.userid = userid;
        this.name = name;
        this.ver = ver;
        this.bexval = bexval;
        this.boidval = boidval;
        this.empid = empid;
        this.fieldname = fieldname;
        this.fieldvalue = fieldvalue;
        this.lstdatetime = lstdatetime;
    }}
```

Am going to retrieve the value from the database,

```
Session session=null;
    Transaction tx=null;
    try{
        session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx=session.beginTransaction();
        Query q=session.createQuery("select a.id.fieldvalue,count(a.id.fieldvalue) from Entries as a where a.id.lstdatetime between '2015-08-01' and '2015-08-24' and a.id.fieldname='*NAME' group by a.id.fieldvalue");
        List<Object[]> list=(List<Object[]>) q.list();
        System.out.println("List size :"+list.size());
        for(Object[] obj:list)
        {
            System.out.println(obj[0]);
            System.out.println(obj[1]);

        }
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception found here :"+e);
    }
```

While retrieve the the value am getting the value from `obj[1]` but in `obj[0]` am getting the object not a value. How can i get the raw data? Any one help me to retrieve the value.

Comment: `in obj[0] am getting the object not a value`. What does that mean. What do you expect the type of obj[0] to be, and what is its actual type? Why don't you fix your database and introduce a primary key? Where are the mapping annotations?

Comment: The `fieldvalue` datatype is `blobe` in the table, in hibernate pojo class it represent has `byte[]`. The database is not created by me, so am not able to insert primary key.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What do you expect the type of `obj[0]` to be, and what is its actual type?

Comment: While looking the database in the `fieldvalue` column it contains country names like US,Canada, India etc... Am expecting the country names as output while retrieve the value in `obj[0]`.

Comment: Well, fieldvalue is mapped as byte[]. So you'll get a byte[], not a String. You can transform this byte array to a String, if you know the encoding used.

Comment: Yes you are right , am getting the byte[] only. How can i convert to String, i tried `String s=new String(obj[0].toString().getBytes())` but there is no change. How can i check the encoding ?

Comment: obj[0] is a byte array. And you want to create a String for it, so use new String(obj[0], encoding). To know the encoding, you need to know how the strings have been stored into this blob in the first place. But you really have a messed up system: no primary key, small strings into a blob. This is a mess, that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hibernate the `fieldvalue`column is represented as `byte[]`, while retrieving the value i directly print the `obj[0]` so i get the byte array as value. To get a value, need to convert that `obj[0]` to string.

```
for(Object[] obj:list)
{
    byte ptext[] = (byte[])obj[0];
    String value = new String(ptext);
    System.out.println(obj[1]+" : "+value);
}
```